# Does GraalVM native image increase overall application performance or just reduce startup times?

Tags: java, graalvm

I’m looking at compiling my Java app using a GraalVM native image but all the documentation I have seen refers to reduced startup times but make no reference to improvements in overall application performance?

So what can I realistically look forward to by doing this?

Answer (score 22):

In general, the performance **decreases**. I have reported the performance decrease of native images [some time ago to the GraalVM team](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/979). The severity of performance decrease may vary on the use case(s). On the benchmarks I have [written and used for my analysis](https://github.com/turing85/graal-playground) (an updated version of the code can be found [here](https://github.com/ConSol/jcon-2019-democode-graalvm)), the overhead ranged from "barely noticeable" to "up to 5x slower". I also mentioned this shortly in my [talk at JCON 2019](https://youtu.be/YQC41cshbkM?t=2643) (#shamelessSelfPromotion).

There is a nice slide from the GraalVM team, illustrating what technology to use for which use case:
[image: As tweeted by @thomaswue]
(The image was taken from a [tweet by Thomas Würthinger](https://twitter.com/thomaswue/status/1145603781108928513))

For the interested reader: As [Andrew mentioned on github](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/979#issuecomment-480786612), a major factor of the bad performance is the non-existence of JIT-compilation: the JIT-compiler can, among other things, eliminate seldom-used branches and thus significantly speed up performance. This is obviously not possible with natively compiled code.

Side note: While we are on the topic of performance, you can execute bitcode emitted by clang (i.e. execute `C`/`C++` programs on GraalVM), but don't expect "good" performance at all...

Comment: In general the peak throughput of a native image is not as great as when you run in the JIT mode though the long-term goal is to improve AOT compilation to be comparable to warmed up JIT. As the image linked explains there are different things people assume when say performance, for example -- lower memory consumption might allow you to scale better and achieve better overall throughput.